# Confused about the behaviour of concat() and the object it returns

Tags: javascript

Consider this example:

```
var a, b, c, d;
a = new Array(1,2,3);
b = "dog";
c = new Array(42, "cat");
d = a.concat(b, c);
document.write(d); // outputs 1, 2, 3, dog, 42, cat - makes sense
```

What I don't get is:

```
alert(b[0]); // d
alert(b[1]); // o
.. etc.
```

I understand `concat()` returns a new array object, but why does it slice the string "dog" into individual array elements? I would've expected `b[0]` to return "dog" and `b[1]` to return undefined. Sorry if this is a stupid question :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the `concat` method. Using the `b` variable as parameter in a call to `concat` doesn't change it.

You are using the bracket syntax to access the items of string, which (in modern browsers) does the same as the `charAt` method.

Answer (score 2):

The square bracket operator `[]` isn't just for arrays. For arrays, it does return the element at the index, but for strings it is implemented to return the `charAt`. See http://blog.vjeux.com/2009/javascript/dangerous-bracket-notation-for-strings.html for potential pitfalls of using it though.